# Azure Batch: Frequency based scheduling

Tags: job-scheduling, azure-batch

How can I configure a frequency based schedule on Azure Batch Service (ex. hourly/daily/weekly job)?

I suppose Azure Batch Service has job scheduling features, but couldn't find a time based scheduling descriptions, although I found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-task-dependencies) that describes dependency based scheduling based on task dependency graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preface: since you didn't specify an SDK language for context, I will reference the REST API documentation for the answer.

You will want to use [Job Schedules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/add-a-job-schedule-to-an-account) to schedule recurrences. You will need to define, at the minimum, the following:

1. Specify a [Schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/add-a-job-schedule-to-an-account#schedule) which will determine how often a job will run along with constraints on when it can run.
2. Specify a [Job Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/add-a-job-schedule-to-an-account#jobSpecification) as per normal (which can include what the job's target pool or autopool, constraints, job manager task if required, job prep/release if required, etc).

Comment: Please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48134928/azure-batch-job-scheduling-job-doesnt-run-recurrently